# Mocking pyodbc without unixODBC installed

Tags: python, mocking, pyodbc, python-unittest

My python app uses pyodbc to connect to the database. I would like to mock the database in my tests.

When running tests on the build server `import pyodbc` throws `ImportError: libodbc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` because unixODBC is not installed.

Is there a way to mock the pyodbc import before importing the main file into the test or do we have to install unixODBC in the build server (works but feels unnecessary)?

main.py

```
import pyodbc

def function_to_test():
    ...
```

test_main.py

```
from main import function_to_test  # this throws

...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're importing `pyodbc` at any point without mocking it, it needs the `unixODBC` libs.

However, you can mock an entire module prior to loading it with the following:

```py
import sys
import unittest
from unittest.mock import NonCallableMagicMock

mock_pyodbc = NonCallableMagicMock()
sys.modules["pyodbc"] = mock_pyodbc

from main import function_to_test  # imports and uses pyodbc

# your tests
```

Comment: "They say" modifying sys.modules is an evil thing... =) But maybe there's no other way...

Comment: @rickythefox it most definitely is not evil if used appropriately and one of the more appropriate uses is mocking, so much so that it's one of the examples in [`unittest.mock.patch.dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-dict).

Comment: JK. Marked as answer.